# React native navigation drawer open over screen upon tab press

Tags: react-native, tabs, react-navigation, navigation-drawer

I am building a react native application where the main screen always has a tab navigator. one of the tabs is a Menu tab, and when pressed on I want it to open a drawer navigator on top of the current screen, not matter what is it.

I tried to input a drawer navigator component to the Menu tab's component( <Tab.Screen name="Menu" component={DrawerNavigator}/> ), but it opens a different screen where I can open the drawer menu - Again, I do not wish to open a different screen for the drawer menu, I wish for the drawer menu to open on top of the current tab screen when the menu tab is pressed.

How can I achieve such functionality?